# SphericalPlot3D taking sign of $r$ into account

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I want to plot `Re[SphericalHarmonicY[l,m,Theta,Phi]]`, with the lobes having different colors depending on the sign of the function. I can’t use `{x, y, z}` coordinates in `ColorFunction` because the sign of `r`, (the function), cannot be determined from these.

How can I do it?

Comment: It's `SphericalHarmonicY`, not `SpericalHarmonicsY`

Comment: Please edit your question to show the plot expression you are working with.

Comment: This is in the docs, under Options > ColorFunction, in the page for `SphericalPlot3D`. Dropping your function into the second example there: `SphericalPlot3D[
 Re[SphericalHarmonicY[2, 1, \[Theta], \[Phi]]], {\[Theta], 0, 
  Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z, \[Theta], \[Phi], r}, ColorData["Rainbow"][r]]]` (The arguments for `ColorFunction` are also explained for this and other plotting functions in the docs for `ColorFunction`, too.)

Answer (score 2):

We can not get *lobes having different colors depending on the sign of the function* using the sixth argument (`r`) in `Function[{x, y, z, θ, ϕ, r}, body]` in specifying the color function because `r` takes only positive values.

Instead, we can use a function that depends on the first argument of `SphericalPlot3D` and add the option `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`.

For example,

```
SphericalPlot3D[Re[SphericalHarmonicY[3, 2, θ, ϕ]], {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, Pi}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, θ, ϕ, r}, 
   If[Re[SphericalHarmonicY[3, 2, θ, ϕ]] <= 0, Blue, Red]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Alternatively, we can use the options [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html), [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) and [`MeshShading`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshShading.html) to get the desired coloring of lobes:

```
SphericalPlot3D[Re[SphericalHarmonicY[3, 2, θ, ϕ]], {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, Pi}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, θ, ϕ, r}, 
    Re[SphericalHarmonicY[3, 2, θ, ϕ]]]}, Mesh -> {{0.}}, 
 MeshShading -> {Blue, Red}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Michael E2 and kglr.  That solves my problem.  Instead of the If Statement or mesh function I used:  Hue[(Sign[Re[SphericalHarmonicY[l,m,\[Theta],\[Phi]]]]+1)/4]

Comment: kglr - Even though your code looks correct I think your images are wrong.